# Написание кратких прилагательных с шипящей на конце

Tags: орфография, прилагательные

Каким правилом нужно пользоваться, чтобы не ошибиться в написании кратких прилагательных с шипящей на конце?

Answer (score 1):

В кратких прилагательных, которые оканчиваются на щипящий, ь не ставится ни в каких случаях. Исключений тоже нет. Колюч, жгуч, певуч.

Answer (score 1):

Краткие прилагательные – особые формы *качественных* прилагательных, которые не склоняются по падежам и отвечают на вопросы: *каков? какова? каково? каковы?*

**Правило**: в кратких прилагательных с основой на шипящую в конце форм мужского рода единственного числа **никогда** не пишется мягкий знак.

Неплохо это правило иллюстрируют русские поговорки:

**Охоч** ездить в гости, да не на чем.
Убери пень в вешний день, и пень будет **пригож**.
Дешев ситец, да **линюч**.
Забор **хорош**, столбы гнилы.
Стар дуб, да корень **свеж**.
Тужил, что поехал охлябь, а воротился **пеш**.
**Тощ**, как хвощ; живет тоненько, да помаленьку.

Comment: Спасибо большое за поговорки! Очень интересные!)

Comment: Мне вдруг захотелось показать особенные словечки "в действии" (если так можно выразиться).

Comment: Это Вам прекрасно удалось! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Вы про хорош, пригож, сведущ - и т.п.?
Правило одно - мягкий знак не нужен.

Answer (score 0):

Мягкий в конце таких прилагательных не нужен. Например: **хорош, жгуч, могуч.**